# Programmatically invoking a Jersey ResourceMethod

Tags: jersey

I have a need to intercept Jersey resource calls and run code before/after each ResourceMethod call.  I have a ModelProcessor and am able to intercept the calls:

```
for(Resource resource: resourceModel.getResources()) {
    for (ResourceMethod resourceMethod : resource.getResourceMethods()) {
        Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder(...);

        resourceBuilder
        .addMethod(resourceMethod)
        .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {
          @Override
          public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
              ...
          }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to call the original ResourceMethod here.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). HK2, which is the underlying DI system for Jersey has [AOP support](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/aop-example.html). See [this example](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return) of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Jersey Filters or Interceptors.
From the documentation:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9368

> Filters and interceptors can be used on both sides, on the client and
>   the server side. Filters can modify inbound and outbound requests and
>   responses including modification of headers, entity and other
>   request/response parameters. Interceptors are used primarily for
>   modification of entity input and output streams. You can use
>   interceptors for example to zip and unzip output and input entity
>   streams.
>
> Interceptors share a common API for the server and the client side.
>   Whereas filters are primarily intended to manipulate request and
>   response parameters like HTTP headers, URIs and/or HTTP methods,
>   interceptors are intended to manipulate entities, via manipulating
>   entity input/output streams. If you for example need to encode entity
>   body of a client request then you could implement an interceptor to do
>   the work for you.

So I think you want to use Interceptor because they will wrap the resource call and you will have access in the same method both before the resource call and after the resource call.

You might also go with Filters, but you will have to break your code to RequestFilter and ResponseFilter.